# Yarn 2 run bin script from dependency with pnp

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, yarn-v2, yarnpkg-v2

I have a custom dependency that has a bin script registered in the package.json:

```
//bin part of package json
"bin": {
    "test123": "./scripts/testtest.js"
  }
```

This script simply makes a console.log.
In my libary I can execute the script with `yarn run test123`, which prints my console.log output.

Now I implement my library in a project and simply register the latest version in my package.json.

With yarn 2 I now want to run the script from the terminal in my project.
How can I do that? I'm using yarn plug n play, so no node_modules folder.

If I do `yarn info @my/library` I even can see that the binary is exposed. So I expect `yarn dlx @my/library test123` should work. But I get the error

`Binary not found (library) for root-workspace-0b6124` (where "library in that error is part behind the / in @my/library)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple: You need to tell yarn explicitly that this is a packe. So

```
yarn dlx @my/library test123
```

works